# matrices and restriction map

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $M_{n}(F)$ be the group of $n \times n$ matrices, where $F$ is a field and $n$ is invertible in $F$.
$$
\mathfrak{sl}_{n}(F) = \{A \in M_{n}(F) : Trace(A) = 0\}
$$
$$
P\mathfrak{gl}_{n}(F) = M_n(F)/FI_n
$$
How to prove that $\mathfrak{sl}_{n}(F)$ is isomorphic to $P\mathfrak{gl}_{n}(F)$?

My attempt:

Since the quotient $\pi: M_n(F) \to P\mathfrak{gl}_n(F)$ is surjective, I want to find the kernel so that $M_n(F)/\ker(\pi) \simeq P\mathfrak{gl}_{n}(F)$, but the kernel is exactly $FI_n$....

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah I know the standard notation means something else...They should be in some German letters and represent Lie algebra, but I don’t know how to latex it so...

Comment: I think they are just general matrices. I don’t think invertibility is important here.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the group operation then?

Comment: Both vectors spaces have same dimension $n^2-1$, so  they are $F$-isomorphic.

Comment: It’s a restriction map so the group operation should be the same as the quotient map.

Comment: Thanks GreginGre! But is it possible to prove it using the isomorphism theorems? And how are we going to use the assumption that n is invertible?

Comment: @GreginGre presumably we are looking for an isomorphism as Lie algebras, but that is not clear from the question.

Comment: The fact that $n$ is invertible allows us to choose a representative of each coset in $M_n(F)/FI_n$ having trace $0$.

Comment: +1 for the person who edited the notation!

Answer (score 1):

Notice first that the Lie bracket $[M,N]=MN-NM$ defines a structure of a Lie algebra on both $M_n(F)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n(F)$. Moreover, $[aI_n,bI_n]=0$, for all $a,b\in F$, so $[,]$ factors to a Lie bracket on $P\mathfrak{gl}_n(F)$ defined by $[M+FI_n, N+FI_n]=[M,N]+FI_n$.

Let $f:M\in \mathfrak{sl}_n(F)\mapsto M + FI_n \in P\mathfrak{gl}_n(F)$. Clearly, this is a morphism of Lie algebras (just look at the definitions of the brackets).

Let us show that $f$ is bijective. As @ancientmathematician says, the fact that $n$ is invertible in $F$ is crucial. Notice that $M-n^{-1}Trace(M)I_n$ has trace zero, and defines the same coset as $M$ in $P\mathfrak{gl}_n(F)$. Hence, $f$ is surjective.

Now $f$ is injective as well. For, if $M\in\mathfrak{sl}_n(F)$ satisfies $M+FI_n=0+ FI_n$, then $M=aI_n$ for some $a\in F$. Taking the race yields $na=0$, and since $n$ is invertible in $F$, we get $a=0$, and thus $M=0$. Consequently, $f$ is the desired isomorphism.